# OLE DB Exception trying to open DBF file: VFPOLEDB.4 provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oledb, visual-foxpro, oledbconnection, oledbexception

I have an ASP.NET MVC application which is compiled as "Any CPU".

I have correctly installed Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro 9.0 from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=14839).

Now I am trying to open a dbf file (that exists) using below snippet code:

```
string conString = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB.4;Data Source=" + dbfFilePath + ";Extended Properties=dBASE IV;";

using (dBaseConnection = new OleDbConnection(conString))
{
   dBaseConnection.Open();
   // Some stuff
}
```

Above code is working correctly when I set to true the feature "Enable 32-bit Applications" from application pool advanced settings:

> IIS Manager -> Application Pools -> My Application Pool -> Advanced
> Settings, I have set to true the setting "Enable 32-bit Applications"

Doing so, I force the process to execute in 32-bit mode and since microsoft visual foxpro OLED DB provider is in x86 then it works perfectly without problems.

Now I need to execute my ASP.NET MVC application in 64-bit mode only so I have set to false the feature "Enable 32-bit Applications". After that the above snippet code stops working. When trying to execute below line of code:

> dBaseConnection.Open();

...it throws below exception:

> VFPOLEDB.4 provider is not registered on the local machine

...and its stack trace:

```
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(OleDbConnectionString constr, DataSourceWrapper& datasrcWrapper)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
   at d:\MyProjects\MyASPNetMvcApp\VfpHelper.cs:line 115
```

How can I make this to run as a 64-bit process (i mean with feature "Enable 32-bit Applications" disabled - set to false)?

Comment: You can't because FoxPro doesn't support 64-bit. Considering the steps you've already take I would have thought this would be obvious, but apparently common sense really isn't all that common nowadays.

Comment: @IanKemp Obviously if the driver is 32-bit only it will not work on 64-bit environments. It's common sense. But here I am asking if there is some way to make it work, for example, using another type of provider able to run under 64-bit mode which let me open/create dbf files in exactly the same way VFPOLEDB.4 does. Does it make sense now? haven't you thought about this before? Before judging me and voting me negative, you should understand what is being asked, don't you think? You could have saved your answer, it does not contribute anything and only offends.

Comment: VFPOLEDB (it is not VFPOLEDB.4 to my knowledge) is 32 bits. You might however try Sybase ADS driver in localserver mode. They claim it supports 64 bits (LocalServer mode is free).

Comment: @CetinBasoz Yes, I know there is Sybase ADS driver available in 32 and 64-bit and it works the same as VFPOLEDB. Currently I am using it but I am not able to make it work, I receive some error message. Please, see my another post about the problem using Sybase ADS driver: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64856440/trying-to-access-to-a-dbf-file-using-advantage-ole-db-provider-throws-an-excepti

Comment: @CetinBasoz I will highly appreciate you if you could help me to make it work using Sybase ADS driver (If you can provide some code snippet, it will help me, maybe I am doing something wrong in my connection string). I have spent a lot of days trying to make it work without success. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually I wasn't using that driver (32 bits ODBC version) since years, I downloaded and tested the 64 bits one (OLEDB).

This code shows an error messagebox which I don't have an idea about ("Exception code C0000005 was generated when calling the user-supplied callbackfunction. It is being disabled."), BUT after you click OK it works (tried with Select and Update): Probably that error message might have something in driver docs.

```
void Main()
{
    string dbfFilePath = @"C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL FOXPRO 9\SAMPLES\Data";
    string conString = @"Provider=Advantage OLE DB Provider;Data Source=" + dbfFilePath + ";ServerType=ADS_LOCAL_SERVER;TableType=ADS_VFP;";

    DataTable t = new DataTable();
    using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(conString))
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from Customer", cn))
    {
        cn.Open();
        t.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        cn.Close();
    }
    t.Dump(); // tested in LinqPad AnyCPU version
}
```

EDIT: With fullpath to dbf:

```
void Main()
{
    string dbfFullFilePath = @"C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL FOXPRO 9\SAMPLES\Data\Customer.dbf";
    string conString = @"Provider=Advantage OLE DB Provider;Data Source=" + Path.GetDirectoryName(dbfFullFilePath) + ";ServerType=ADS_LOCAL_SERVER;TableType=ADS_VFP;";
    DataTable t = new DataTable();
    using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(conString))
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand($"select * from {Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dbfFullFilePath)}", cn))
    {
        cn.Open();
        t.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        cn.Close();
    }
    t.Dump(); // tested in LinqPad AnyCPU version
}
```

PS: This works without any error message on first run. On repeated run it displays the exception I mentioned before. Should be related to object disposal.

EDIT2: I forgot to mention, the foldername in connection string is not really important and you could select with fullpath. ie:

```
void Main()
{
    string dbfFullFilePath = @"C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL FOXPRO 9\SAMPLES\Data\Customer.dbf";
    string conString = @"Provider=Advantage OLE DB Provider;Data Source=c:\temp;ServerType=ADS_LOCAL_SERVER;TableType=ADS_VFP;";
    DataTable t = new DataTable();
    using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(conString))
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand($"select * from [{dbfFullFilePath}]", cn))
    {
        cn.Open();
        t.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        cn.Close();
    }
    t.Dump(); // tested in LinqPad AnyCPU version
}
```

Comment: As I can see you pass a folder into dbfFilePath. I supose in that folder there are some dbf files (*.dbf), right? But I want to pass and then open a concret dbf file that I have within a concret folder, let's say, c:\my_data\example.dbf so can I pass the path "c:\my_data\example.dbf" into dbfFilePath in order to read only that dbf file and not all the dbf files within c:\my_data ?

Comment: Hmmm, I actually never tried to put full path of a single file there. To my knowledge, it is either a folder or fullpath of a VFP database (.dbc) which is a container for tables. It is like that with other OLEDB backends too. For example, with SQL server it would be the name of a Database and not a table within the database.

Comment: If you meant, how you could do it passing your fullpath, then in the procedure where connection is made, you can split the filename to its directory name and just the filename for the query itself, using Path. I will edit for a sample soon.

Comment: Hi again, if I use c:\MyApp\Temp\MyTable.dbf as dbFullFilePath it does not work, I get error 7707 The Advantage Data Dictionary cannot be opened. axServerConnect AdsConnect. However If I use c:\MyApp\Temp (within this there is a MyTable.dbf file) as dbFullFilePath then open command works but later when I try to execute an insert on MyTable using oleDbComand.ExecuteNonQuery, it gets stuck, it does nothing, no errors thrown, simply it does nothing, it seems stuck.

Comment: Please see update 2020/11/20 at the end in this post (I have posted there code and explained it): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64856440/trying-to-access-to-a-dbf-file-using-advantage-ole-db-provider-throws-an-excepti